# Javascript function to match string patterns

Tags: javascript, pattern-matching

I've been working on this problem for a long time now and I'm looking for some help. I've searched for help on this problem, but I keep finding posts about regex and wildcard matching. I want to write a Javascript function that takes 2 strings as input, and outputs true/false if the second string matches the "pattern" of the first string.

Example 1:

```
string1 = 'abca'
string2 = 'xxqrzzxx'
output = true
```

In this example, 'a' = 'xx', 'b' = 'qr', and 'c' = 'zz'.
Other possible string1 "patterns" using the characters in string1 would be 'aabccaa', 'aabdccaa', 'aabdcaa', and 'abdcca'. I chose 'd' for the fourth unique character arbitrarily.

Example 2:

```
string1 = 'abaq'
string2 = '1234p1234qwerrewq'
output = true
```

In this example, 'a' = '1234', 'b' = 'p', 'q' = 'qwerrewq'. Of course, this is just 1 of many possible patterns.

Example 3:

```
string1 = 'abaq'
string2 = '1234p1234qweppewq'
output = false
```

In this example, 'b' = 'p' as in the previous example and it is used again in the 'qweppewq' sequence so the "closest" pattern to string1 would be 'abaqbbq'.

Here's what I have so far, I know it's not even close to the solution. I'm pretty sure I need to create a recursive function to generate all the character sequence possibilities, but I'm not sure what it would look like.

```
let patternMatching = (str1, str2) => {

  let patterns = {};
  let examples = {};
  let array = [];
  let pattern = str1.split('');
  let example = str2.split('');

  pattern.forEach((element, index) => {
    if (!patterns[element]) {
      patterns[element] = index;
      array.push(element);
    }
  });
  example.forEach((element, index) => {
    examples[element] = index;
  });

  let uniques = Object.keys(examples).length;
  for (let i = 0; i < uniques; i++) {
    let obj = {};
    let copy = str2.slice(0);
    obj[array[i]] = copy.slice(i, 1); // or recursive function
    while (j < uniques) {
      let result = '';
      pattern.forEach(char => {
        result += obj[char];
      });
      if (str1 === result) return true;
      j++;
    }
  }

  return false;
};

let pattern = 'abc';
let example = 'xxyyzz';
console.log('pattern', pattern);
console.log('example', example);
console.log(patternMatching(pattern, example));
```

Please redirect me if this question has been answered before.

Comment: ?? Are the patterns pre defined or does the code have to find if a pattern can be created? That would of course require at least one duplicated character in the first string.

Comment: How is "pattern" determined?

Comment: Google "artificial intelligence"

Comment: Blindman67, the code would have to find if a pattern can be created from the string1 unique characters and if any of those generated patterns match the string1 input.